# How to set View data in calendar view by power shell using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, view

I want to create a calendar view in a calendar list using CSOM power shell for SharePoint online.

I am able to create a view using PowerShell but the calendar columns are not set. I want to set the below values using CSOM:

```
<ViewData>
  <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarMonthTitle" />
  <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarWeekTitle" />
  <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarWeekLocation" />
  <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarDayTitle" />
  <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarDayLocation" />
</ViewData>
```

`View.Viewdata` property is used in server side to set the above values, I need it in client side.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this a bit late, but this may help someone. You can update the `viewdata` property of a view on the client-side with something along these lines:

```
$siteURL = "http://sp.myfirm.com/fwc"  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  
$view = $ctx.web.Lists.GetByTitle("Firm-wide Calendar").Views.GetByTitle("Calendar")          #View name you want to customise
$view.ViewData="<FieldRef Name=""ColourTitle"" Type=""CalendarMonthTitle""/><FieldRef Name=""ColourTitle"" Type=""CalendarWeekTitle""/><FieldRef Name=""FCLocation"" Type=""CalendarWeekLocation""/><FieldRef Name=""ColourTitle"" Type=""CalendarDayTitle""/><FieldRef Name=""FCLocation"" Type=""CalendarDayLocation"" />"
$view.Update()  
$ctx.Load($view)   
$ctx.executeQuery()
```

As you can see, the viewdata property just needs the XML markup, minus the viewdata tags.